# Have different placeholders for search inputs on the same page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

If you use the searchform.php in wordpress to show search input boxes. How can you show different placeholders in different search boxes on the same page? For example, I have one page that has a search box in the footer, in a widget in the sidebar and on the main navigation menu. I wish to show different placeholders on each one.

This is what i've got in my searchform

```
<!-- Searchform -->
<form method="get" class="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
    <input id="s" placeholder="Search..." type="text" name="s" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" >
    <input class="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="<?php _e( '', 'mytheme' ); ?>">
</form>
<!-- /Searchform -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do, but the general idea is pretty simple. Just create the placeholder text conditionally.

```
if (is_home()) {
  $placeholder = "Search Posts...";
} elseif(is_tag()) {
  $placeholder = "Search Tags...";
} else {
  $placeholder = "Search...";
}

<!-- Searchform -->
<form method="get" class="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
    <input id="s" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" type="text" name="s" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = '';"
```

Is that something like what you are looking for?

**Based on some further explanation of the requirements**

The search form functionality isn't really meant to work like you want. You can cheat around it with global variables.

Put

```
$GLOBALS['placeholder'] = "Default placeholder value";
```

in `functions.php` then edit your form to read...

```
<!-- Searchform -->
<form method="get" class="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
    <input id="s" placeholder="<?php echo $GLOBALS['placeholder']; ?>" type="text" name="s" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = '';"
```

And call the function like:

```
$GLOBALS['placeholder'] = "Placeholder value...";
get_search_form();
```

According to the docs, `get_search_form(false)` should return a string, which means that something like this should work:

Edit the search form to read:

```
<!-- Searchform -->
<form method="get" class="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
    <input id="s" placeholder="%s" type="text" name="s" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = '';"
```

And then use...

```
$search_form = get_search_form(false);
printf($search_form,'Placeholder...');
```

That avoids the globals, which is generally a good thing. I could not that to work out of the box. If you look at the source, that functionality seems to be dependent upon the presence or absence of `searchform.php`. If that file exists it is simply included, which makes the "return a string" part pretty dicey. And it has proven surprisingly difficult to hijack using the available filters.

To avoid the `global` juggling, I think you will need to replace `get_search_form', for example, with:

```
function my_get_searchform($placeholder = 'Search') {
  $search_form_template = locate_template('searchform.php');
  if ( '' != $search_form_template ) {
    ob_start();
    require($search_form_template);
    $form = ob_get_clean();
    printf($form,$placeholder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite, i have a page with 3 search boxes in different locations. One of them is quite small so I don't want it to have a placeholder. It should be more of a location if statement, but I am unsure how to do that. Something like: If search is in #main-menu then show no placeholder

Answer (score 0):

The get_search_form() function prints out the code from searchform.php.  Instead of using get_search_form() in your page, take out that function and copy the code from searchform.php and paste it where you want the search bar to show. Then change the placeholder text accordingly.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Header Stuff -->
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="main-navigation-menu">   
            <!-- Searchform -->
            <form method="get" class="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
                <input id="s" placeholder="PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE" type="text" name="s" onfocus="if    (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" 
                onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" >
                <input class="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="<?php _e( '', 'mytheme' ); ?>">
            </form>
            <!-- /Searchform -->
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
           <div class="widget">
               <!-- Default widget stuff from functions.php will appear here. Searchform styling will come from searchform.php -->
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">   
            <!-- Searchform -->
            <form method="get" class="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" >
                <input id="s" placeholder="PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE" type="text" name="s" onfocus="if    (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = '';" 
                onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" >
                <input class="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="<?php _e( '', 'mytheme' ); ?>">
            </form>
            <!-- /Searchform -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Keep the searchform.php and style that file how you want your widget search form to appear.